# How to make IntelliJ to break javadoc lines on </p>

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

I was using `</p>` tag to break lines in Javadoc. It was both old-fashion and working in Elcipse. Unfortunetely, it does not work in IntelliJ:

[image]

As you see, there is no wrap between "to javadoc" and "This is it".

Simultaneously, Eclipse works fine:

[image]

Code is follows (don't regard image path -- it is from other test):

```
package tests.helloworld;

/**
 * This is try to javadoc</p>
 * This is it
 * <img src="/myimage.jpg">
 */
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Of course generated javadoc is OK in browser:

[image]

Comment: Did you try using proper HTML in your Javadoc (i.e. surround "This is try to javadoc" with both a `<p>` start tag *and* a `</p>` end tag)?

Comment: I wish to use single closing tag, because it conserves typing. It is working everywhere except `IntelliJ`.

Comment: P.S. Sure, if I use two tags, it shows ok.

Comment: In this case, you should just use single `<p>` tags between paragraphs, instead of single `</p>` tags after paragraphs ([random source](http://blog.joda.org/2012/11/javadoc-coding-standards.html)) or use `<br>` tags instead ([other source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260368/javadoc-paragraph-separator)).

Comment: If I use just `<p>` it will affect DOM structure and, consequently, may affect styling (first chunk will not tagged with `<p>`).

Comment: That's true. However, as I've said, simply separating paragraphs with `<p>` tags is conventional.

Comment: P.S. `<p>` is worse than `</p>` because IntelliJ automatically adds closing tag `<p></p>`, so it requires extra efforts to delete it :)

Comment: Where did you get the `</p>` syntax from? If you *really* don't want to use well-formed HTML, at least use the proper syntax for self-closing elements: `<p/>`. This works in IntelliJ IDEA, and it won't add an opening tag automatically.

Comment: `</p>` is completely different, than `<p/>`. Latter is equivalent to `<p></p>` while former is an orphan tag, which pair is deduced automatically by most browsers (except `IntelliJ`).

Comment: But the result (a line break caused by a new paragraph) is exactly the same. In fact, both `<p/>` and `</p>` work *exactly* the same in Chrome - the result is `<p></p>` (haven't tried other browsers). IntelliJ isn't a browser and I wouldn't expect it fixing this bad-formed syntax. It's nice that Eclipse does this, but it doesn't make your request any more valid. You want to use a single tag, because it conserves typing. Now you've got one (`<p/>`), with the expected result. If this is still not enough, consider contributing to IntelliJ code.

Answer (score 4):

While `<p> [...] </p>` formatting is probably more concise/understandable, if you *just* want line breaks you can use `<br>`:

```
/**
 * This is try to javadoc<br>
 * This is it
 * <img src="/myimage.jpg">
 */
```

Example:
[image: screenshot example]

Comment: For some reason `</br>` won't work with IntelliJ. Just `<br>` works fine.

Comment: Well, `</br>` is not valid in any context. If you however mean `<br />`, that works just as well as `<br>`.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use `<p>` instead of `</p>`. The opening tag is required in HTML, while the closing `</p>` tag may be omitted in certain cases.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p:

> The start tag is required. The end tag may be omitted if the `<p>`
>   element is immediately followed by an `<address>`, `<article>`,
>   `<aside>`, `<blockquote>`, `<div>`, `<dl>`, `<fieldset>`, `<footer>`,
>   `<form>`, `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `<h4>`, `<h5>`, `<h6>`, `<header>`,
>   `<hr>`, `<menu>`, `<nav>`, `<ol>`, `<pre>`, `<section>`, `<table>`,
>   `<ul>` or another `<p>` element, or if there is no more content in the
>   parent element and the parent element is not an `<a>` element.

In Javadoc, usually there's either another `<p>` tag or there is no more content in the parent element so this works.

Answer (score 2):

Note: If you searched for JavaDoc using Kotlin:

On IntelliJ IDEA 2020 neither `<p></p>` nor `<br>` work for Kotlin, only a blank line.
Even worse, sentences in `<p></p>` are not displayed at all.

[KDoc Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html)

[image]